# How would I write this using Set Theory Notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have an ordered pair of $(x, y)$, and I wanted to have a set of every possible integer instance of $(a \le x \le n, a \le y \le n)$. How would I write this using set theory notation?

I though of $(a \le x \in Z \le n, a \le y \in Z \le n)$, with $Z$ of course being the set of all integers, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

EDIT: Sorry, I meant to write ordered pair, but in its application I was thinking of arrays

Comment: Maybe something like $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb N^2 : x, y \leq n\}$? (using the convention where $0 \in \mathbb N$)

Comment: This is the set $\{a,a+1,\dots,n\}^2$. For more pair-related shorthand, look up the Cartesian product of sets.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put a variable instead of 0

Comment: Could I write it then something like {(x,y) ∈ Z^2 : a ≤ x,y ≤ n}?

Comment: Less ambiguously: $\{\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb Z^2: a\leq x\leq n~,~a\leq y\leq n\}$, or simply $[[a .. n]]^2$

Comment: You can use `\mathbb{Z}` to get $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired set is

$$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Z}^2\mid a\leq x,y\leq n\}.$$

Comment: Why is x less than/equal to y?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write ordered pair, but in its application I was thinking of arrays. If that's not why that property exists, then I'm lost.